# ImportError: cannot import name 'CONTRACTION_MAP' from 'contractions'

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, data-science, contractions

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-74c9bc9e3e4a> in <module>
      8 from nltk.tokenize.toktok import ToktokTokenizer
      9 #import contractions
---> 10 from contractions import CONTRACTION_MAP
     11 import unicodedata
     12 

ImportError: cannot import name 'CONTRACTION_MAP' from 'contractions' (c:\users\nikita\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\contractions\__init__.py)
```

One question is: is the `CONTRACTION_MAP` variable deprecated from the `contractions` package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you have mistaken the `contractions` package available on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/contractions/) with the `contractions` module from a textbook called "Text Analytics with Python" ([source code](https://github.com/dipanjanS/text-analytics-with-python/tree/master/Old-First-Edition)).

The `CONTRACTIONS_MAP` variable is defined in the latter and is not part of the `contractions` package API (documented in the [GitHub Readme.md](https://github.com/kootenpv/contractions)).

From the documentation, the package can be used to fix contractions like:

```
import contractions
contractions.fix("you're happy now")
# "you are happy now"
```

If you want access to the map of contraction to expanded version, this can be imported using:

```
from contractions import contractions_dict
```

This `contractions_dict` contains entries like:

```
{..., 'you’ll': 'you will', ...}
```

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dipanjanS/text-analytics-with-python/master/Old-First-Edition/Ch03_Processing_and_Understanding_Text/contractions.py

File for easy access.

Answer (score 1):

after you install contractions by pip install contractions, you can use contractions_dict instead of CONTRACTION_MAP